# PDO_MSSQL and SQL Server 7

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have problem with establish connection with sql server 7 on different server using PDO/PHP. All works perfect on win 2003 32 bit/apache/php5.2.5 but I receive server not found when service is on win 2008R2 64bit/apache/php5.2.5. User/password are correct, firewall configured.

I check, that PHP don't use 1433 port but try connect with 445 and 139 ports.

Any idea?

Stefan

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to connect?

Comment: try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mssql:host=x.x.x.x;dbname=yyy', 'username', 'andpassword');
    var_dump($dbh);
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}

Comment: can you connect to the server using the windows datasources connection?

Comment: Windows datasources connection? I can connect by ASP (classic) and ADODB and by external program to manage db.

Comment: If you setup the connection via Control Panel > Data Sources

Comment: Yeap, connection establish by "test connection" button in "data source administrator" window. But can I use dsn name in PDO? I didn't found any information about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated;

You could use the PDO ODBC connection option: [PHP: PDO_ODBC DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php). I've used this method previously to connect from Win 2003 and 2008 to a SQL Server

Comment: Ok what about - $cnx = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=250.156.0.1;Database=myDataBase; Uid=userName;Pwd=thePassword;");

Comment: One step forward :) PDO ODBC works perfect. But there is one problem why I don't use this. Service was written in zend framework. There is no PDO_ODBC for that framework.

Comment: Ahh so your using the Zend pdo_dblib extension?

Comment: Also, you could try using the hostname rather than the IP. Before I did have an issue (I can't remember what way around it was though) where it would connect via host but not IP (Or IP but not host - can't remember.)

Comment: Finally done. Problem was in old ntwdblib and .NET. After update to newer dll and installing .net 1.1 php finally start to connect with 1433 port. Alex, thanks for your time and advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your PDO statement, the first param would do well to take this form:
"mssql:host=x.x.x.x;port=xxxx;dbname=xxxxxxx;"
Notice the inclusion of port.